# Using a side bar makes the right edge of my content sometimes disappear

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I finagled this tutorial to work great with my .NET, C#, MVC project except that now the far-right edge of content disappears when the browser window gets any smaller than a 1080p monitor.

Here's the tutorial: http://seegatesite.com/create-simple-cool-sidebar-menu-with-bootstrap-3/

Note that I didn't follow it to the T, rather I added their CSS and JS files to my Visual Studio project and created a new layout that works with it and can be applied to my other views - a great achievement for Novice me...

I'm sure there's just a CSS variable or two somewhere that I need to update to keep the right-hand edge of content from occasionally disappearing.

Here's what it looks like:

This: [image: Hidden Right]  vs this: [image: OK Right]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap, it is part of the grid system functions.

Meaning, we have xm md lg right? I will not go through all of these because it is covered in the documentation already.

Now having a class that hides something when it is on a specific window or Browser width. Is very easy, even to explain.

The one that you want is called. ***Responsive utilities*** under Bootstrap.

```
<div class =".visible-sm">
       I am visible only for small devices.
</div>
```

Now .visible class will only show from a specific devices Grid.

For example

**Browser width or Device width is >= 768px .visible-sm is "VISIBLE"**

**Browser width or Device width is >= 992px .visible-md is "VISIBLE"**

**Browser width or Device width is >= 1200px .visible-lg is "VISIBLE"**

Take note. They will only be visible if they are on the specific width and will not show on the other width. ex .visible-md will not show on 768px and 1200px. Only on 992px.

In most cases, this is not a very easy task to use, if you want to cover a smart response.

Now we have another class which is.

```
<div class=".hidden-sm">
        I am visible to Medium and Large, but I will then Disappear when the browser is small
  </div>
```